# Encode the Id parameter only

Tags: reactjs, url, parameters, decode, encode

i am trying to encode only Id parameter like this. but this isn't work for me.

here is my code . i am using react.

```
<Link to={`/savecoachingdetails?Id=${encodeURIComponent(item.id)}&edit=true`}>
Edit
</Link>
```

I want to encode id parameter only in URL